# how to pass Image "src" data(with folder address) Bootstrap modal?

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-modal

This is my Modal link

```
   <div class="blog-content">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-flat red-text p-1 my-1 mr-0 mml-1 collapsed" data-blog_id="{{$item->id}}" data-blog_title="{{$item->title}}" data-blog_content="{{$item->content}}" data-blog_image="{{$item->image}}"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalScrollable">Read More</button>
   </div>
```

This Is my Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalScrollable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalScrollableTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header"> </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <h5 class="modal-title py-3 text-center" id="title" name="title" style="font-family: 'Bitter', serif;"></h5>
                        <img class="card-img-top rounded-0 pb-2" name="image" src="" alt="no image">
                        <p class="text-justify" id="content" name="content" style="font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;">

                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
    </div>
```

This my My Bootstrap modal js from where i trying to set the address of image "src".
is this the correct way of sending the "src" because i have stored the photo in this directory " public/storage/blog/images/"

```
$('#exampleModalScrollable').on('show.bs.modal',function(event){
        var button= $(event.relatedTarget)
        var title= button.data('blog_title')
        var content=button.data('blog_content')
        var image=button.data('blog_image')
        var blog_id=button.data('blog_id')
        var modal= $(this)
        //modal.find('.modal-title').text('Edit Blog'); 
        modal.find('.modal-body #title').text(title);
        modal.find('.modal-body #content').text(content);
        modal.find('.modal-body #data-image').attr("src", "{{asset('public/storage/blog/images/"+ $(this).data(image) + "')}}");
        modal.find('.modal-body #blog_id').val(blog_id);

    })
```

Comment: The blade syntax won't work in .js files. Why not just send the url as `data-img_src` and use `button.data('img_src')`?

Comment: Can you please elaborate this ?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. You want to make this part properly right? `modal.find('.modal-body #data-image').attr("src", "{{asset('public/storage/blog/images/"+ $(this).data(image) + "')}}");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd pass the img url as data attribute:

```
<div class="blog-content">
  <button data-img-src="{{ asset('/storage/blog/images/' . $this->image) }}"></button>
</div>
```

And in javascript, access it with `$(this).data('img-src')`

`modal.find('.modal-body #data-image').attr("src", $(this).data('img-src'))`